# Manipulating factored expression for convenient limit calculation

Tags: expression-manipulation

Consider the following example expression dependent on parameter `t`:

```
expr= t a ((t b+t c+ d )(t e+ f)+t g (t k+ l)+m (t n+ p));
```

This is a very short expression, which stands as an example for more complicated ones that are much larger, more nested and of higher overall degree in `t`.

Now I would like to take the limit:

```
Limit[expr/t^3,t->Infinity]
```

However, instead of doing it using this function, I would like to manipulate `expr/t^3` such as to cancel most `t` parameters without opening any brackets, so that we get:

```
 expr2=myManipulate[expr/t^3]
```

> `a (( b+ c+ d/t )( e+ f/t)+ g ( k+ l/t)+m (n+ p/t)/t)`

Now we can see that taking the limit amounts to just setting `t->Infinity`:

```
expr2/.t->Infinity
```

> `a ( e ( b+ c )+ g k)`

We did not have to open any brackets and did not have to use `Limit` function. Is there a way to write an efficient `myManipulate` function that does this for arbitrarily more complicated (larger and more nested) input? Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should recursively reshape the expression.

Rules below work with your example, though I expect they wouldn't with a more complicated one. You'd probably want to divide innermost polynomial by its order, not just linear power `y`.

```
divide[x_ /; Depth[x] <= 3] := Expand[x]

divide[Times[x_Plus, y : _^_?Negative]] := Expand[x y]

divide[Times[x__Plus, y_^p_?Negative]] :=
 Module[{n, k},
  n = Length[{x}];
  k = Min[n, -p];
  (Times @@ Join[
      Table[divide[z/y], {z, Take[{x}, k]}],
      Drop[{x}, k]])/y^Max[-p - n, 0]]

divide[Times[x_, y_Plus, z : _^_?Negative]] := 
 Times[x, divide[z #] & /@ y]
```

#### Example

```
e1 = t a ((t b + t c + d) (t e + f) + t g (t k + l) + m (t n + p));

e2 = divide[e1/t^3]
```

> a ((b + c + d/t) (e + f/t) + g (k + l/t) + m (p/t^2 + n/t))

```
e2 /. t -> Infinity
```

> a ((b + c) e + g k)

Comment: This looks useful! I am not sure I understand all the syntax. Does it specialize on cases when two things (like your `x` and `y`) are multiplied and would require a further rule for three things or more?

Comment: @Kagaratsch Check `?divide`, rules are tried in that order. First rule matched, first fired. You should think about expressions in their `FullForm`.